# Possible causes of PCI nic card and motherboards eth ports not available for use by os?

Tags: linux, rhel, network-interface, ethernet

hi all so I have an old linux server that was resurrected for a particular reason and I flashed the server with the image of redhat 6 that was previously used for these servers. after doing so though the os does not make the pci nic card placed in a pci expansion slot available I cant even see it as a device using ifconfig, now I can see the 2 ports attached to the motherboard in ifconfig but these too are not available or managed by the network manager service. This is what I am seeing from my end.

```
>ifconfig
eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:96:91:4E:13:F1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Memory:fb100000-fb200000 

eth5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:96:91:4E:13:F0  
          inet addr:192.9.200.11  Bcast:192.9.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Memory:fb200000-fb300000
```

this is what I pulled from dmesg that looked relevant

```
pci 0000:09:00.0: [8086:1533] type 0 class 0x000200
pci 0000:09:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xce800000-0xce87ffff]
pci 0000:09:00.0: reg 18: [io  0x5000-0x501f]
pci 0000:09:00.0: reg 1c: [mem 0xce880000-0xce883fff]
pci 0000:09:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
pci 0000:09:00.0: PME# disabled
pci 0000:00:1c.2: PCI bridge to [bus 09-09]
pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xce800000-0xce8fffff]
pci 0000:0a:00.0: [8086:1533] type 0 class 0x000200
pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xce700000-0xce77ffff]
pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 18: [io  0x4000-0x401f]
pci 0000:0a:00.0: reg 1c: [mem 0xce780000-0xce783fff]
pci 0000:0a:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
pci 0000:0a:00.0: PME# disabled


pci 0000:81:00.0: [8086:1521] type 0 class 0x000200
pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xfb200000-0xfb2fffff]
pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 1c: [mem 0xfb304000-0xfb307fff]
pci 0000:81:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
pci 0000:81:00.0: PME# disabled
pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 184: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:81:00.0: reg 190: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:81:00.1: [8086:1521] type 0 class 0x000200
pci 0000:81:00.1: reg 10: [mem 0xfb100000-0xfb1fffff]
pci 0000:81:00.1: reg 1c: [mem 0xfb300000-0xfb303fff]
pci 0000:81:00.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
pci 0000:81:00.1: PME# disabled
pci 0000:81:00.1: reg 184: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:81:00.1: reg 190: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit pref]

NET: Registered protocol family 10
igb 0000:81:00.1: changing MTU from 1500 to 9000
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth4: link is not ready
igb 0000:81:00.0: changing MTU from 1500 to 9000
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth5: link is not ready
type=1400 audit(1628863781.555:4): avc:  denied  { sys_tty_config } for  pid=6008 comm="kexec" capability=26  scontext=system_u:system_r:kdump_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kdump_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=1400 audit(1628863781.556:5): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=6008 comm="kexec" path="/dev/pts/0" dev=devpts ino=3 scontext=system_u:system_r:kdump_t:s0 tcontext=syste


dca service started, version 1.12.1
Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 3.2.10-k
Copyright (c) 2007-2011 Intel Corporation.
igb 0000:81:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 50 (level, low) -> IRQ 50
igb 0000:81:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 110 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 111 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 112 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 113 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 114 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 115 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 116 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 117 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: irq 118 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
igb 0000:81:00.0: eth0: (PCIe:5.0Gb/s:Width x4) b4:96:91:4e:13:f0
igb 0000:81:00.0: eth0: PBA No: H47819-003
igb 0000:81:00.0: Using MSI-X interrupts. 8 rx queue(s), 8 tx queue(s)
igb 0000:81:00.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 52 (level, low) -> IRQ 52
igb 0000:81:00.1: setting latency timer to 64
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 119 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 120 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 121 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 122 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 123 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 124 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 125 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 126 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: irq 127 for MSI/MSI-X
igb 0000:81:00.1: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
igb 0000:81:00.1: eth1: (PCIe:5.0Gb/s:Width x4) b4:96:91:4e:13:f1
igb 0000:81:00.1: eth1: PBA No: H47819-003
igb 0000:81:00.1: Using MSI-X interrupts. 8 rx queue(s), 8 tx queue(s)
```

so I can see they are all there as well as the pci id I also checked to make sure the device driver was present and it is and is loaded

```
lsmod | grep igb
igb                   113015  0 
dca                     6877  1 igb
```

I saw that the igb kernel driver was being used for the expansion card but not the onboard ethernet ports on the motherboard could this cause them all to be inaccessible? any advice on how to correct the issue of my ports not being available to the os would be greatly appreciated

So I verified that the onboard ethernet controller is a intel i210 8086:1533 which also uses the igb driver so I started down the path of uninstalling and reinstalling the igb driver. the kernel is a 3.2 rt so igb is supported from like 2.6+ I think I am good there but after running rmmod igb and then trying to run a " make install" from a tar file of the latest igb release the make fails taking about it confilicts becuase "netdev_features_t" already exists and so on. I thought ok well that is probably left over from the previous igb driver that was installed, well when I run the following to complete remove igb

```
rpm -q igb

rpm -e igb //or igb<kernel version>
```

rpm finds no module to uninstall or does not exist
so does anyone know where to find the left over reminants of a partially uninstalled device driver? I have wiped out every igb file I know of and the make still fails. list of files removed

```
/usr/src/kernel/<kernelversion>/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb //wiped out whole directory containing the original makefile

/lib/modules/kernel/<kernelversion>/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb //dir containing the .ko file
```

was there another place the the original .o files still exist
I also booted to a live fedora image and it saw all 4 ports and used igb for both with no issues so I feel like it has to be the driver.

Comment: Try running `lspci` as root. The "capabilities: access denied" means your current user does not have the permissions necessary to read the I/O addresses where the capabilities are stored. That's very normal and happens on every Linux system. To debug your actual problem, have a look at `dmesg` after boot.

Comment: yes you were correct I could see the capabilities as root. I added the dmesg info like you asked I can see that the kernel driver igb is only being called by the expansion nic and not the motherboard eth ports any ideas how to debug the why on that issue?

Comment: It's normal that different hardware uses different drivers. You didn't say how you "pulled out" the information from `dmesg`, potentially you overlooked something. Please put the complete `dmesg` after boot in a pastebin etc. and add a link. I can see `eth0` and `eth1` getting initialized, but nothing for `eth2` and `eth3`, and nothing for the `eth4` and `eth5` that are actually present. First guess is that your kernel is too old and you may need newer drivers or firmware. Even while sticking with RHEL 6 you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `ifconfig` without options shows only configured NICs; you'll need `ifconfig -a` to see the unconfigured ones too. And if the card is left unconfigured (e.g. because the MAC address of the card does not match the address listed in existing configuration), then the driver will not reserve any resources for it either, and that could be why your `dca` use count is just `1`.

Check `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` for any lines tying a NIC with a particular MAC address to a particular `eth*` name. If the disk image was not from this specific system, you'll most likely find some MAC addresses referring to the NICs of the system this image was taken from. You can either comment those lines out, or edit them if you want to assign specific names to specific NICs.

Then also check any `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*` files for MAC address references. They will look like `HWADDR=<MAC address here>`.  Those may or may not exist: this used to be the legacy RedHat way of ensuring persistent NIC naming, that pre-dates udev's `70-persistent-net.rules`. I would recommend removing any `HWADDR=` lines altogether and letting udev rules handle the NIC name assignment.

If you had `HWADDR=` lines for your "missing" NICs, you may find in your system logs a message or two from `ifup` matching this template:

```
"Device ${DEVICE} has MAC address ${FOUNDMACADDR}, instead of configured address ${HWADDR}. Ignoring."
```

That would be RHEL 6's way to say "Woah, this network configuration does not match this hardware. I'm not touching anything on that NIC; let the system administrator sort this out."

Comment: So ifconfig -a also doesn't show the motherboard ethernet ports and after looking in the /etc/udev/rules.d/70-Persistent-net.rules I found 2 lines pointing to the hardware address of the expansion card. I commented these lines out and then on reboot udev just recreated them. so I uncommented them and wrought similar rules for the motherboards 2 ethports and pointed to there mac address which I got from lspci. after reboot I got the same result not access to any and ifconfig -a still only shows 2 adapters- I am going to check dmesg again and also reinstall the driver